# Find any cell values >= x in Pandas dataframe and return cell value, column header, row and neighbouring cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I realise this is quite a lengthy ask, but I have been trying to solve this for days now with no success and wondered if anyone might have some ideas.

Consider a spreadsheet like so:

```
        apple1  grape1  apple2  grape2  apple3  grape3
1          0       4     -0.2     2       0       4
2          0       4       0      6       0       3
3        -0.1      2       0      4       0       4
4        -0.5      5       0      6     -0.2      5
5        -0.4      4       0      5       0       2
6          0       6     -0.1     5       0       3
```

I would like to search my dataframe for any cell with a value less than -0.1, and write the value, column header, row number, and neighbouring value out.

At the start, I though it might be as simple as something along the lines of:

```py
Newlist()

if df >= -0.1:
   Newlist.append(cell.value)
   Newlist.append(row.value)
   Newlist.append(column.value)
   Newlist.append(cell.value.shift(1))
```

I fully realise the above makes no sense, but I hope it conveys the idea of what I've been trying to do.

Next, I could convert the df to a list and work from there( using an ifnot >= -0.1 to delete objects?), but this seems inelegant and far from ideal. I am however open to this if anyone can get it to work.

I must have looked at every stack exchange question ever posted on this without managing anything so apologies if I've overlooked something very obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your expected output to make [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, your title and question contradict each other with _cell value >=x_ in title and _cell with a value less than -0.1_, which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to filter your dataframe you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) like this :

```
df[df >= -0.1]
```

This way, all the data that is not superior to -0.1 will be displayed as nan, you can then use [Pandas.isnull()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.isnull.html#pandas-isnull) to identify them.

To get the row and columns of the data you want, you could turn your dataframe into an array with [df.to_numpy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) and iterate over the rows and columns with [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep the id of row/column you are currently iterating through :

```
my_data = df[df >= -0.1].to_numpy()
for idrow, row in enumerate(my_data):
   for idcol, col in enumerate(row):
       if not pd.isnull(col):
           print("Value :"+str(col)+" column:"+str(idcol)+" row:"+str(idrow))
```

This will result in something like this :

```
Value :0.0 column:0 row:0
Value :4.0 column:1 row:0
Value :2.0 column:3 row:0
```

You can get columns name by using this in the loop :

```
df.columns[idcol]
```

Once you got those ids, you can get the neighbouring values by direct access ie.

```
my_data[x][y]
```

Just remember to set a condition to not access value that are not in the array !

Comment: Thank you so much for this bruce, it's working brilliantly. The only section I'm having trouble with is right at the end with the my_data[x][y]. I would like to print this under your original phrase so e.g. print("some_word  :+my_data[str(idrow)[str(idcol)+1]).  This however is throwing up some funny errors.

The main problem is sorted however so thank you a tonne for that!

Comment: The errors might be because you try to access element that are not in the array. For example if you have an array like this : x = [0,1,2,3], accessing x[4] will result in error as the array don't have a 5th element. This works in both dimensions. Also you must use an integer to access data contained in an array. with my_data[str(idrow)][str(idcol)+1] you are using string ! so just do my_data[idrow][idcol+1]